# Getting a pdf from scipy.stats in a generic way

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

I am running some goodness of fit tests using `scipy.stats` in Python 2.7.10.

```
for distrName in distrNameList:
    distr = getattr(distributions, distrName)
    param = distr.fit(sample)
    pdf   = distr.pdf(???)
```

What do I pass into `distr.pdf()` to get the values of the best-fit pdf on the `list` of sample points of interest, called `abscissas`?

Comment: [Here are all the scipy.stats distributions PDFs with example code.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559471/2087463)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To evaluate the pdf at `abscissas`, you would pass `abcissas` as the first argument to `pdf`. To specify the parameters, [use the `*` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/190597) to unpack the `param` tuple and pass those values to `distr.pdf`:

```
pdf = distr.pdf(abscissas, *param)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

distrNameList = ['beta', 'expon', 'gamma']
sample = stats.norm(0, 1).rvs(1000)
abscissas = np.linspace(0,1, 10)
for distrName in distrNameList:
    distr = getattr(stats.distributions, distrName)
    param = distr.fit(sample)
    pdf = distr.pdf(abscissas, *param)
    print(pdf)
```

Answer (score 8):

From the documentation, the [`.fit()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) returns:

> shape, loc, scale : tuple of floats
>   MLEs for any shape statistics, followed by those for location and scale.

and the [`.pdf()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf) accepts:

> x : array_like
>   quantiles
>
> arg1, arg2, arg3,... : array_like
>   The shape parameter(s) for the distribution (see docstring of the instance object for more information)
>
> loc : array_like, optional
>   location parameter (default=0)
>
> scale : array_like, optional

So essentially you would do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# some random variates drawn from a beta distribution
rvs = stats.beta.rvs(2, 5, loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)

# estimate distribution parameters, in this case (a, b, loc, scale)
params = stats.beta.fit(rvs)

# evaluate PDF
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
pdf = stats.beta.pdf(x, *params)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)
ax.hist(rvs, normed=True)
ax.plot(x, pdf, '--r')
```

[image]

Comment: very nice, +1 for graphs and elaboration, but in essence this did not add to the unutbu's answer -- or am I mistaken?

Comment: No, not really - I didn't have time to finish typing my answer before unutbu posted his

Comment: i did +1, but unfortunately, cannot accept... thank you very much